# subquery that uses a value from the outer query in the where caluse

Tags: mysql, database

I wanna run a subquery that uses the value of the outer query in its where clause. Here's and example of what I wanna do:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl1`
WHERE `tbl1`.`max_count` < (
SELECT COUNT(*) rc FROM `tbl2`
WHERE `tbl2`.`id` = `tbl1`.`id
)
```

There is tbl1 with a column named max_count, and there is tbl2 with rows referring to a row in tbl1(many-to-one relationship). What I wanna do is select rows in tbl1 where the number of rows in tbl2 referencing it is less than the max_count value of that row. But I'm pretty sure that what I wrote here, ain't gonna cut it. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl1` t1
    WHERE t1.`max_count` < (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl2` t2
    WHERE t2.`id` = t1.`id`
    )
```

Comment: I chose this answer over the other two, because I'm using this in a view, and using any of the other two would make the view code a lot more complicated. BUT THE IRONY is that my own code in the question would work too. When I tested this answer and saw that it's working, I tried it without the aliases and worked again. :D

Answer (score 1):

try using `JOIN`.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    tb1 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    tbl2
            GROUP   BY id
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   a.max_count < b.totalCount
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution, it's probably easier to just use a `LEFT JOIN` with `HAVING` than a subquery;

```
SELECT tbl1.*, COUNT(tbl2.id) current_count
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 
  ON tbl1.id=tbl2.id
GROUP BY tbl1.id
HAVING COUNT(tbl2.id) < max_count
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d6c8/2).

Note that the `GROUP BY` in this case is a MySQL only thing, normally you'd need to `GROUP BY` every selected field in tbl1 even if tbl1.id is known to be unique per row.